# Call Webmethod by ref/out parameters in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, webforms

Here is my `webmethod`

```
[WebMethod]
    public string CheckService(string name, ref string msg)
    {
        return "Hello" + name;
    }
```

and this is my `ajax` call

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<%= ResolveUrl("integrator.asmx/CheckService") %>",
                    data: '{name: "zakki",msg:"" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data1) {
                        console.log('', data1.d);
                    }
                });
            });
```

It raises an error

```
Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.String&'
```

Comment: All parameters in `WebMethod` must use pass-by-value, you cannot use `ref` (and `out`) keyword(s) for that.

Comment: What's the point of `ref` in your method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: You cannot use pass-by-reference (with `ref`/`out` keywords) for parameters in a method marked with `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Here is the reason that explains why `&` added for second `System.String` type in exception message, taken from [this reference](http://projectsmm.com/technet/asp/index.shtml):

> The key to decoding the source of this message is the "&" located in
>   the end of the text. This is the syntax used when passing a parameter
>   to a function BYREF (By-Reference) & used in
>   C-Notation to indicate "pass the AddressOf" variable name. Even if you coded
>   the WebService in C#/VB.NET, Microsoft will convert/compile it in C type
>   notation when it outputs it as an assembly.

Therefore, all parameters inside a method which uses `[WebMethod]` attribute must use pass-by-value, by removing `ref` keyword:

```
[WebMethod]
public string CheckService(string name, string msg)
{
    // return string here
}
```